# advice for how to improve implementation skills of "clean" c++ code

Tags: c++, architecture, coding-style

I'm a software major student and my first programming book was "Clean Code" by Robert C Martin. So I know the importance of clean code and trying to apply it to my code.

However, if I try to implement the algorithm I learned from university, it just messed up. I can solve the problem through my hands but it's hard to do with a computer. And even I code a class of algorithm through c++, it normally violates clean code principles(The most severe one is so many parameters of method.)

Recently, to improve my skills, I'm trying online judges but it doesn't help my code clean much...

Could you advise me about this according to your experience? I really want to make my code clean and also well designed. I'll sooo appreciate you!

+I have a code of algorithm for knapsack problem made by backtracking method. If you want, I can post it but probably messy and hard to understand... T_T

Comment: There's really no shortcut to this.  Learn by doing.  Accept that pretty much most of the code you'll write in your life will be garbage, and you'll feel better about the times when you write something really beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with code tests is that they are often contrived and do not reflect real-world examples.

Often when I have designed programs the requirements have been set out in a way that reflects the existing paper-based systems that they intend to computerise.  This is a fair place to start for conveying the "problem domain" however it doesn't go quite far enough.  To take it to the next step, you need to be able to analyse what's needed for a system with use cases, scenarios and "stories".  From then you can identify at a top level how your system should work.

At the same time, you also need to work "bottom up" by writing small pieces of code, each to achieve a single task.

By breaking down the problem in this fashion, it enables you to focus on single parts of the system at both high-level and low-level.  By identifying actors, use-cases and scenarios, you then have some reasonable idea of how to structure your code and delegate appropriately.

I can recommend a book which tremendously helped me rethink how to approach the problem solving part - "Design Patterns Explained": https://www.amazon.co.uk/Design-Patterns-Explained-Perspective-Object-Oriented/dp/0321247140/ref=sr_1_1